# ¿Como obtener la fecha de los últimos 30 días en javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Buen día.
Actualmente quiero obtener la fecha de 30 días atrás a partir de hoy `18/03/2019` es decir obtener la fecha 16/02/2019 ya que del 16/02 al 18/03 existe la diferencia de 30 días, actualmente solo he logrado obtener el primer día del mes y el ultimo, mediante un ejemplo:

```
let date = new Date();
let  primerDia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 2);
let  ultimoDia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

console.log(primerDia.getDate() +"--"+ultimoDia.getDate())
```

y lo que quiero es obtener la fecha que cayo hace 30 días atrás, dicha fecha poder mostrarla en forma timestap.

De antemano muy agradecido, soy nuevo trabajando con fechas en javascript.

Bendiciones.

Comment: revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24049314/5215609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos porque no haces una resta simple algo asi:

```js
 //fecha actual
 var dt = new Date();
console.log('Fecha Actual: '+dt);
//restando los dias deseados
dt.setDate( dt.getDate() - 30 );
//mostrando el resultado
document.write('Hace 30 dias fue: '+ dt );
```

Como puedes notar es algo sencillo para mas detalles la documentacion: [JavaScript Date Metodos](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_date_methods.asp)